# how to allocate one variable to two columns of a txt file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file which contain Timestamp columns. My file is like below: I need to read the file and allocate one variable for the Timestamp like this: t= 2014-08-26 19:49:32, which contain two columns of my file. I can make them as a string with code below, but the problem is that I need it to be as a Timestamp. So how can I read these Timestamp from the file line by line?

```
2014-08-26 19:49:32  0 7Z.HOLU..HHZ   
2014-08-28 05:43:21  0 7Z.HOLU..HHZ   
2014-08-30 11:47:54  0 7Z.HOLU..HHZ
```

```
lines = m.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        o=line.split(' ')[0]+ ' '+line.split(' ')[1]
        r= pd.Timestamp(o)
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with pandas or was that an incorrect addition through the edit?

Comment: That is right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To convert a date string to a timestamp:

```py
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "2014-08-26 19:49:32"
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
1409107772.0
```